# Prove that the state fidelity for pure states has the form $\langle\psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

For two density operators $\rho$ and $\sigma$, the fidelity is given by
$$
F(\rho,\sigma)=\left(\mathrm{Tr} \sqrt{\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}\sigma\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)^2
$$For a pure state $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$, fidelity is given by
$$
F = \langle \psi| \sigma |\psi\rangle
$$
However I have not been able to show this. I do not know how to find out $\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$. Any clue regarding how to proceed would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: $\rho^{1/2}$ is defined through the spectral representation of $\rho$. Or, here equivalently, as the unique positive operator for which $\rho=\rho^{1/2}\rho^{1/2}$. Now since for a pure state $\rho^2=\rho$ -what do you conclude?

Comment: And please use MathJax!

Comment: @TobiasFünke yeah, understood. I do not know about MathJax. Would try learning it!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\rho$ is a pure state, then $\rho^2=\rho$, and thus also $\sqrt\rho=\rho$.
Furthermore, if $\rho=|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$, then $$(\rho\sigma\rho)^{1/2}=\langle \psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle^{1/2} \rho,$$
hence
$$(\operatorname{tr}[\sqrt{\rho\sigma\rho}])^2 = (\langle \psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle^{1/2})^2 = \langle \psi|\sigma|\psi\rangle.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answered your question, consider to "accept" it. See e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And since none of your other question has been accepted either, also consider it for those...

Comment: @TobiasFünke okay!